# Как под цифрами сделать их тень? Фотография прилагается

Tags: html, css

[image]Думаю сделать это при помощи позиционирования, но думаю есть ещё способы, как сделать это, поэтому пишу сюда

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C

Comment: text-shadow - в эту сторону можете посмотерть

Comment: Тут явно не тень, а просто ещё один блок с теми жи цифрами, но другим шрифтом (более жирным)

Comment: @AlexeyTen Попробовал с помощью теней - ничего не получилось( Думаю сделать при помощи отдельного блока и позиционирования